# Tomcat Manager - Change sessionsList.jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, tomcat

I want to change the table from the page `/manager/html/sessions` of Tomcat.

The `jsp` file for that page is `tomcatpath/webapps/manager/WEB-INF/jsp/sessionsList.jsp`

I want to add a new column in table which contains the path of last page which client has requested.

Ex: if the last request of client is `mydom.com/path/3`, I want to show in table `/path/3`

This is the part where are iterated all sessions

```
<%
  for (Session currentSession : activeSessions) {

       String currentSessionId = JspHelper.escapeXml(currentSession.getId());
       String type;
       if (currentSession instanceof DeltaSession) {
           if (((DeltaSession) currentSession).isPrimarySession()) {
               type = "Primary";
           } else {
               type = "Backup";
           }
       } else if (currentSession instanceof DummyProxySession) {
           type = "Proxy";
       } else {
           type = "Primary";
       }
       
       //I have problem getting the last accessed path by client.
       String lastPath = ...;

%>

//html where is printed every row with data from session
//use here <%= lastPath %>

<% 
  } //end of for 
%>
```

I don't know how to extract the last accessed path.

`Tomcat version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.20`

Comment: _"how to extract the last accessed path"_: unfortunately that is not an information usually available in a session (cf. [`HttpSession`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-10.0-doc/servletapi/jakarta/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) but also Tomcat's [`StandardSession`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/session/StandardSession.html)). You can however write a servlet `Filter` or Tomcat `Valve` to persist this information in a session attribute.

Comment: That's why I asked cause I don't know what information Tomcat provide to JSP, I was thinking there is more info. Thanks for advice